# Core dumps aren't generated in El Captain

Tags: terminal, macos

I used `ulimit -c unlimted` in terminal to get core dumps in the `/cores` folder.
However, after reboot (kernel panic) I no longer can get any core dumps regardless what I try - `ulimit -c unlimted` or `sudo sysctl -w kern.coredump=1` - core dumps just don't get generated.

How should I enable core dumps for the terminal session? I used core dumps to debug my console application.

OSX 10.11.5

Answer (score 1):

The issue was missing sticky bit on the `/cores` directory permissions:

```
$ ls -lh /
...
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  admin    68B Jul 29 09:55 cores/
...
```

fixed by:

```
sudo chmod 1775 /cores
```